# Will FromAsyncPattern dispose of resources no longer used?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, resources, system.reactive

Will FromAsyncPattern close my webresponse:

```
var o = Observable.Return(HttpWebRequest.Create("http://foo.com"))
                  .SelectMany(r => Observable.FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(
                      r.BeginGetResponse,
                      r.EndGetResponse)())
                  .Select(r => r.ContentLength);
// The response is now disposed
```

Or do I have to do it manually?

```
var o = Observable.Return(HttpWebRequest.Create("http://foo.com"))
                  .SelectMany(r => Observable.FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(
                      r.BeginGetResponse,
                      r.EndGetResponse)())
                  .Select(r => Tuple.Create(r, r.ContentLength))
                  .Do(t => t.Item1.Close())
                  .Select(t => t.Item2);
```

If I have to do it manually, is there a better way than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As slightly cleaner version of the `Using` query would be this:

```
var o =
    from rq in Observable.Return(HttpWebRequest.Create("http://foo.com"))
    from cl in Observable.Using(() => rq.GetResponse(),
        rp => Observable.Return(rp.ContentLength))
    select cl;
```

I would suggest adding `Scheduler.ThreadPool` to at least the first `Return` to make the observable execute on a background thread - the default is `Scheduler.Immediate` otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

`Observable.Using` can be used for this purpose as:

```
var o = Observable.Return(HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com"))
                  .SelectMany(r => Observable.FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(
                      r.BeginGetResponse,
                      r.EndGetResponse)())
                  .SelectMany(r =>
                  {
                      return Observable.Using( () => r, (resp) => Observable.Return(resp.ContentLength));
                  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that `FromAsyncPattern` could close your resources, even if it wanted to.  It does not have enough information about how either the object on which it is making the async calls (HttpWebRequest in this case) or the object returned from the async calls (WebResponse in this case) will be used elsewhere to know when it is save to `Dispose`.

That said, you can still close the resources manually without the extra `Do` and `Select` calls.  Just change the `Select` in the first example to:

```
.Select(r => { using (r) { return r.ContentLength; }});
```

The only Rx operator that will call `Dispose` that I know of is `Observable.Using`.  However, based on its signature, it was not immediately obvious how or if it could apply here, so I went with the above approach.